How to increase query string length in Blazor wasm hosted on Azure static website
Blazor WASM standalone (C#,.NET 6) app hosted on Azure static app and the same code for test purposes on Azure Web App.
Project contains web.config in a root project folder and has property PublishIISAssets set to true.
Web.config has the following settings:
<system.web>
 <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength = "16384" maxUrlLength="32768" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="16384" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>

App hosted on Azure Web App works perfectly and accepts query string up to the limit defined in web.config.
But the same code hosted on Azure Static App shows error (404) as soon as query string length is over 4K. It looks like web.config settings do not apply to standalone Blazor hosted on static app.
Is there any way to increase query string length when Blazor app is hosted as Azure Static?
I tried to manipulte with values in web.config, expecting that Blazor hosted on Azure Static App will accept query string longer than 4K. No luck.

BTW, your <system.web><httpRuntime...> element is entirely superfluous today. You only need the <system.webServer> element now.

Out of curiosity, what do you want such a long query-string for? You have a static website so there's no server-side code that needs to process querystrings. If you're talking about the #fragment part of a URI, that's not sent to the server and doesn't count towards the querystring length.

Are you sure..Web.config` file  is deployed to your blazor app?

@Harshitha. It's definitely deployed as using Azure Web App Dev tools you can see directories and files deployed. Unfortunately Static App does not have this tool.

@Dai Azure B2C generates redirect URL well over 4K

AFAIK,you cannot use web.config file for static web apps.

Are you able to work with query string length less than 4k.

Not fully. B2C - no,  but custom is fine, thanks to @Dia for the clue about #fragment

@VSuser - Is your issue resolved?
